# Google Maps causes horizontal scroll on mobile

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps JavaScript API (v3) to display two maps on my website. When viewing the [this page](http://www.wallz.co.il/%D7%92%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%99-%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%99-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%9B%D7%A4%D7%A8-%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94/) **on mobile** (Asus Zenfone 2 with Chrome), I see a blank page that is caused by an unwanted huge horizontal scroll - and it's the map's fault. When I remove the map from the code, there is no horizontal scroll. When I use `overflow: hidden` on the map's container, or even the `<body>` - the scroll is still there. Even when I use `display: none` on the map's container, I still have this annoying scroll.

Any suggestions on how I keep this map in mobile view, and get rid of this scroll?

Comment: Do you need to use `position:absolute` on the map containers?  Try without.

Comment: It wasn't it, and I had to use it, because the maps are one over another, and I need them both to load on document load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the map generates a `span` at the end of the `<body>`. The fix was simple:

```
body > span {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the map inside of a div that sizes itself responsively, then call `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')`

You can also prevent this from happening my making sure that the div is built before the map is rendered, for example by adding a 'show map' button or an event listener after the user scrolls past a certain point.

Comment: That didn't do the trick. The maps wrapper is already responsive, and also I tried to set the wrapper width by script before the map is generated, and that did not work also. I get the right width, but the scroll remains.

Comment: Hi, Yuval, did you find a solution? I've the same problem. Thanks, Chen

Comment: I did. See my answer.